# From Ingress to NodePort service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

On AWS EKS, I have ALB Ingress Controller with Ingress resource pointing to NodePort service on port 32509 with targetPort 80, with `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` on service.

How is external traffic routed to my pods under NodePort service in this case?

Something like, ALB > random Node kube-proxy > Node port 32509 (?) > Pod port 80? 

Edit: kube-proxy is working in iptables mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NodePort service builds on ClusterIP. But if the `externalTrafficPolicy` is Local, then traffic arriving at a node is forwarded only to pods that are on this node. So, the way your traffic is routed must be something like this:

```
ALB -> random node on port 32509 -> random pod on this node on port 80
```

The problem is that if there are no pods of the NodePort service on this specific node, then the request is dropped. This is explained [here](https://www.asykim.com/blog/deep-dive-into-kubernetes-external-traffic-policies) in detail.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm using podAntiAffinity already. I figured I must have at least one target pod on each node for this to work.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So, an appropriate pod anti-affinity and at least as many pods as there are worker nodes should guarantee that.